# how many bits represent the value 2G

Tags: hardware, boolean-logic

When we say 4K in hardware it is equal to the value 4096 which is 11 bits. What would be the value for 2G and how many bits represent this value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often in CS we deal with number that are necessarily power of two (all addressable quantities for example).
In this context is it more useful to have prefixes that instead of being multiple of ten, like the *decimal* **K** = *10^3*, **M** = *10^6*, **G** = *10^9*, are multiple of two.

Since the power of two closest to 1000, which is decimal *K*, is 1024 = *2^10*, we can make the analogy that in CS *K* 1024 instead of 1000.

This is rather confusing as some quantities (like disk sizes or transmission channel parameters) are not bound to be power of two and can be given with either the decimal *K* or the CS *K*.
To avoid further confusion the CS now use appropriate [binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix), for example the CS *K* now is the *Ki*.

So as in decimal *G* is *10^9* = *(10^3)^3* which you can think of as *K^3* then *G* in binary (better called *Gi*) is *Ki^3* = *(2^10)^3* = *2^30*.

To represent 4Ki quantities you need **12** bits as *log2(4Ki) = log2(2^2 * 2^10) = 12*.
To represent 2Gi quantities you need *log2(2Gi) = log2(2 * 2^30) = **31*** bits.

**Note** I used the phrase *"To represent 4Ki quantities"* rather then *"To represent the 4Ki quantity"*, the latter is different and need one more bit. This is analogous to saying that to represent 1000 quantities we need 3 decimal digits (from 000 to 999) but to represent the number 1000 itself we need 4 digits (1, 0, 0 and 0).